# Two brighter lines in scanned documents

Tags: scanner

I have a Canon MF4320-4350 scanner. Just recently, when I scan a document, two bright line artifacts emerge in the scan. Any ideas to solve the problem?

[image: Canon MF4320-4350 image artifacts]

Answer (score 0):

The imaging device of the scanner is broken. Replace either the scanner part or the entire unit.